# C# Changing txtBox BackColor by Length

Tags: c#, winforms, background, textbox

I want to write a simple "registration/login" program, just for me, just for fun.

I want to change the color of the TxtBox where a user types their name. When `txtBox.Length<4` it should change its background to red.

I don't know why my code below isn't working. When I solidly change a text in txtBox properties to more than 5, it's blue at the start but doesn't change afterwards.

My code :

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _4Fun
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (regTxtBoxName.TextLength<4) {
                regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else{
                regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
            }
        }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void regBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (regTxtBoxName.TextLength < 4)
        {
            txtBoxStatus.Text = "Choose a name with minimal length 5. "; // Urobit txtboxname a pass v registru červene pozadie ak x<4
        }
        else {
            txtBoxStatus.Text = "Your account has been successfully created.";
            string name = regTxtBoxName.Text;

        }
        if (regTxtBoxPass.TextLength < 4)
        {
            txtBoxStatus.Text = txtBoxStatus.Text + "Choose password with minimal length 5. ";
        }
        else {
            txtBoxStatus.Text = "Your account has been successfully created.";
            string pass = regTxtBoxPass.Text;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is setting the color in the constructor of the form and then you don't change it. You need to register to `TextChanged` event on your `TextBox` to change the colour while your application is running based on how many characters there are in your `Textbox`.

Answer (score 2):

Handle your text box [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, and place this code there, **not** in constructor:

```
if (regTxtBoxName.TextLength<4) {
    regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
else{
    regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `Textbox` [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event.
Here is code

```
void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (textBox1.TextLength<4) 
  {
      textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
  }
  else
  {
     textBox1.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
   }
}
```

When you enter a text in text box `TextChanged` event will call. check this link http://www.dotnetperls.com/textchanged

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the `regBtn_Click` method to `regBtnTextChanged`. By doing so, then the color of the textBox will change on run time.

So the code would be:

```
private void regBtnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (regTxtBoxName.TextLength<4) {
            regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else{
            regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
        }
    }
```